# SQL rules being ignored

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have two tables on a SQL database:

`MODEL` (`ID_MODEL`, `MODEL`, `ID_manu`, `ID_CLASS`) and `CLASS` ( `ID_CLASS`, `CLASS`)

They are linked using the `ID_CLASS`.

The query to delete information has a none rule, so it's supposed to give an error when I try to delete a row from `CLASS`, if the `ID_CLASS` is being used on the `MODEL` table.

But it's being ignored. It's deleting the `CLASS` from the `CLASS` table and the row on the `MODEL` table is removed from the `DataGridView`, but it's kept on the table.

The `ID_CLASS` options on `MODEL`is a `NOT NULL` as you can see below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MODEL] (
    [ID_MODEL] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [MODEL]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [ID_manu]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [ID_CLASS] INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_MODEL] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([MODEL] ASC)
);
```

Even after deleting and recreating the relationship its still happening.

Also there are two other tables with a similar configuration (same rule and data type) and on that it's working as expected. It retrieves an error every time the delete query is run.

Comment: You don't have a foreign key defined on Model table.

Comment: How have you defined this "rule" in the database if there's no foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add foreign key on dbo.Model:

```
alter table dbo.Model
add constraint FK_Model_Class foreign key (ID_Class) references dbo.Class(ID_Class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had only created the relationship on the datadesigner.

Its working now.